# Is the tag "latin-america" more accurate than using the tag "south-america"?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The tag [latin-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america) has just popped up, and before it starts becoming something more used on the SE, I was wondering if it would be better to use tags for North America and South America (the continents).

I'm not from either of these areas so I was wondering if using the tag [latin-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america) better describes the *cultural* background than using North and South America tags.

Edit: I am aware that latin america isn't the same as South America, what I'm saying is would it be better to have the collection of tags [south-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-america), [north-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-america) **OR** [latin-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-america), [united-states](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [canada](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you know your geography. You are right, of course. What seems clear is that having *both* "south america" and "latin america" as tags  could be confusing.   ***South America is a geographical, not a cultural term***. Since most of South America is included within Latin America, and especially since Mexico and a lot of Spanish speaking Central American countries are culturally Latin American rather than North American, it makes sense to have the set of cultural tags "USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "North America" (for both USA and Canada) "Caribbean" and "Latin America" while OP can always feel free to specify the exact country in a tag, or someone else can create the tag based on information from OP, if OP lacks the points.

Comment: No. Not all of South America is included in Latin America.

Comment: You are right and I shall amend it to "most" -- thanks for pointing out @Catija.

Answer (score 5):

[Latin America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_America) **is not** South America. It's specifically countries in North, Central, and South America that primarily speak Spanish or Portuguese languages.

It includes pretty much everything south of the US and some (but not all) of the Caribbean Islands, so it includes Central America and excludes primarily French and Dutch-speaking countries like Guyana, and Suriname.

So, if the person asking the question is from Mexico, using [south-america](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-america) would be completely wrong!

We should always try to get as much information as possible but we shouldn't retag things without knowing the new tag is correct.

Comment: I'm aware that the places are different, just wasn't sure if from a cultural point of view if using latin america was more appropriate than using (the combinations of) North and South America.

Comment: We're interested in culture, not the country you're in.

Comment: That's the question I was trying to ask, is it *better* to use latin america to describe a cultural area (as opposed to the two continents it (mainly) spans) :P

Comment: Telling us that you're in the US but us finding out later that everyone in your family are Indian transplants is useless... we need the culture of the people. Indians in the US is important to know... the US is of less value than the "Indian" part, though.